# responsive background image fit width and height/ no cover

Tags: css, background-image

I'm having a container with `height: 100vh;` . This contaier has a background image. I want the background to be responsive and fit the entire div. Using `background-size: cover` doesn't make it look good. How can I achieve this? Thanks

Comment: can you please specify "doesn't make it look good" ?

Comment: If you share a fiddle, it would help. You could also try to set `background-size: contain`. From w3c 'contain' does this: 'Scale the image to the largest size such that both its width and its height can fit inside the content area'

Answer (score 3):

it depends on what you are looking for, there are many options:

1. `background-size:contain` it will stretch to max width and height to
   fit the container, rest of the space will be background-repeated if
   you dont set `background-repeat:no-repeat`
2. `background-size:100% 100%;` will stretch your background to 100% of width and height of container but this will change your image proportions-image will be deformed
3. `cover` will stretch image so whole area is covered with image, but
   rest of the image will be croped (as you already discovered)

you can also use css (percentual padding top/bottom) to have responsive container with given proportion and so have both, full image cover and no-croped sides

Comment: nice explanation of the three different possibilities!

Comment: Why this isn't the accepted answer. Nice explanation!